# Laravel 6 - @push and @stack

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-6

Hello everyone I'm new to Laravel and I'm currently using Laravel 6.0

For some reason my javascript using @push is not working. The script only works when I paste the code in the blade file and not using the asset folder.

**add.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
// Long HTML code
@endsection

@push('scripts')
<script src="{{ asset('js/position.js') }}"></script>
@endpush
```

**layouts > app.blade.php**

```
 <main class="py-4">
      @yield('content')
    </main>
  </div>
  @stack('scripts')
</body>
```

**public(asset) > js > position.js**

```
 $('#department').change(function(){
    var departmentID = $(this).val();    

        if(departmentID) {
        $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url:"{{url('get-section-list-position')}}?department_id="+departmentID,
        success:function(res){               
            if(res) {
            $("#section").empty();
            $("#section").append('<option>Please Select Section</option>');
            $.each(res,function(key, value){
            $("#section").append('<option value="'+key+'">'+value+'</option>');
          });
          } else {
            $("#section").empty();
          }
        }
      });
    } else {
        $("#section").empty();
    }      
  });
```

If I paste the script in the add.blade.php and used @section, it works but I'm afraid that the security of my system would be compromised. Please help.

Comment: Does the console show any thing in regards to your script?

Comment: So the script doesn't show up in the source code or does it just not run? Do other scripts work when being `@push`ed? Do you get any errors in your browser console? Does your `add.blade.php` extend `layouts/app.blade.php`?

Comment: @Script47 Nope it doesn't show anything. But I tried using console.log('hello') it appears in the console.

Comment: @kerbholz The dynamic drop-down doesn't work. Yes, I tried using console.log('hello') and it appears in the console. Yes, it has the code @extends('layouts.app')

Comment: I tried enclosing it all in a document ready, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: We are following the same pattern and it works fine. Does your `position.js` load in `view page source` ?

Comment: if you see a broken a page or script after viewing the `position.js` script link then you are doing something wrong in `asset`. And can you tell me if you just `alert` something maybe string inside `@push('scripts')` does it work ?

Comment: @AkhtarMunir Yes doing console.log('hello') inside a push works, it display the message in the console. My position.js is located inside the public > js folder path. Yes it appears in the view page source. It seems like there is something wrong with my syntax in pathing.

Comment: I know it will appear in view page source, but when you click it mean to say click on it in view page source, it will be just like a link, so does it show error or your code ? when open the link in the view page source ?

Comment: And where is your index file located ? in root or in public ?

Comment: @AkhtarMunir No error once I clicked the link from view page source, it shows the exact code as I pasted above.

Comment: What do you mean? Where add.blade.php is located? It is resource > views > positionview (folder) > add.blade.php

Comment: No i meant to say, the `index.php` file but if your code shows correctly, then it 's fine.

Comment: But one thing, why are you doing this ? lets say if you have code in your `position.js` this page is also for more stuff as well, so if you want to use it, then it will also be shown inside page view source, and maybe it may slow down your page performance as well.

Comment: The push works like it throws a piece of code from every page to where you have loaded it. So, it reduces the performance issues on that specific page.

Comment: The index.php is in the root folder. Yeah it makes sense, we can still actually see the script itself when clicking the link. I think I would stick with pasting the script itself in the blade.php. Thank you @AkhtarMunir!

Comment: Of course, we can't parse the jquery itself. Welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Javascript won't work as standalone because it won't get parsed by Blade, but it contains `{{url('get-section-list-position')}}`. Either change `{{url('get-section-list-position')}}` to the "hardcoded" URL or place your Javascript code inside your `@push('scripts')` if you want to use Blade directives:

```
@push('scripts')
<script>
$('#department').change(function(){
    var departmentID = $(this).val();    

        if(departmentID) {
        $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url:"{{url('get-section-list-position')}}?department_id="+departmentID,
        success:function(res){               
            if(res) {
            $("#section").empty();
            $("#section").append('<option>Please Select Section</option>');
            $.each(res,function(key, value){
            $("#section").append('<option value="'+key+'">'+value+'</option>');
          });
          } else {
            $("#section").empty();
          }
        }
      });
    } else {
        $("#section").empty();
    }      
  });
</script>
@endpush
```

Comment: This works just like with @section. But I have a question doing this, will it make the system vulnerable? It seems like this can be seen in a view page source.

Comment: Not more than it would using an external javascript, which can also be viewed in your browser.

Comment: You're right, I just complicate things. I think I will stick to this method. Thanks @kerbholz!

Comment: Not a problem, glad I could help